# JBoss 5.1/JAAS/Kerberos Authentication - ERROR [UsersRolesLoginModule] Failed to load users/passwords/role files

Tags: jboss, jaas

We have a use case where a web app running on JBoss 5.1 (say Application A) needs to programatically log into another application (say Application B). Application B uses Kerbros as its authentication mechanism.

1. We first created a standalone client that is able to successfully log into Application B using JAAS and Java GSS-API. So that works.
2. Next, we created a very simple, HelloWorld Like web app, with only one servlet. Inside the doGet method of this servlet we incorporated the same code as the standalone client we had created in #1 and deployed it to a fresh install of JBoss 5.1. When this servlet is invoked, we see the exception inlined below.
3. The same servlet web-app when deployed to Weblogic 10.x works without any changes, as is.

What are we missing here? My hunch is that JBoss has a implementation of the security APIs (`org.jboss.security.auth.spi.*`) that is being picked up by the server at runtime in place of the default JRE implementation, causing this exception. So how do we tell JBoss not to use its own implementation? What needs to be doen to make this work inside JBoss 5.1?

I am listing entire code from inside the test servlet below. Please let me know if any further information is needed, I will be happy to provide.

Code:

```
package test;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.Principal;
import java.security.PrivilegedAction;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.security.auth.Subject;
import javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext;
import javax.security.auth.login.LoginException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.apache.oozie.client.AuthOozieClient;
import org.apache.oozie.client.OozieClientException;
import org.ietf.jgss.GSSContext;
import org.ietf.jgss.GSSCredential;
import org.ietf.jgss.GSSException;
import org.ietf.jgss.GSSManager;
import org.ietf.jgss.GSSName;
import org.ietf.jgss.Oid;

public class HelloWorld extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Oid KERB_V5_OID;
    private Oid KRB5_PRINCIPAL_NAME_OID ;

    private Properties hdfsProperties = new Properties();
    private Properties jobProperties = new Properties();

    private String userId = "xyxyxyxy";

    private String pw = "abcabcabc";


    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public HelloWorld() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(response.getWriter());
        writer.write("Hello");
        loadProperties();
        createOid();
        Subject subject = new Subject();
        LoginContext lc = login(subject);
        Principal userPrincipal = createUserPrincipal(subject);
        try {
            submitOozieWorkflow(lc, userPrincipal);
        } catch (LoginException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
    }

    public LoginContext login(Subject subject) {
        String realm = hdfsProperties.getProperty("kerberos.realm");
        String kdc = hdfsProperties.getProperty("kerberos.kdc");
        System.setProperty("java.security.krb5.realm", realm);
        System.setProperty("java.security.krb5.kdc", kdc);
        System.setProperty("java.security.auth.login.config",hdfsProperties.getProperty("jaas.conf"));

        LoginContext lc = null;

        try {
            lc = new LoginContext("Krb5LoginContext", subject);
            lc.login();    // **<----Exception gets thrown here**
        } catch (LoginException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                throw new java.lang.IllegalStateException(e);
        }
        return lc;
    }

    public void loadProperties(/*String command, Properties hiveProperties*/) {
        hdfsProperties.put("jaas.conf", "C:/tmp/jaas.conf");
        hdfsProperties.put("hadoop.service.account", "zzzzzzzzz");
        hdfsProperties.put("kerberos.realm", "DEV.HDFS.COM");
        hdfsProperties.put("kerberos.kdc", "lcdre30348.xxxxxxxxx.com:88");
        hdfsProperties.put("kerberos.application.principal", "krbtgt/DEV.HDFS.COM@DEV.HDFS.COM");

        // Job Properties
        // standard
        jobProperties.put("jobTracker", "lcdre30347.xyzyxzxyz.com:8021");
        jobProperties.put("nameNode", "hdfs://lcdre30346.xyzyxzxyz.com:8020");
        jobProperties.put("oozie_server", "http://lcdre30348.xyzyxzxyz.com:11000/oozie");
        jobProperties.put("oozie.libpath", "/user/oozie/share/lib");
        jobProperties.put("oozie.wf.application.path", "hdfs://lcdre30346.xyzyxzxyz.com:8020/user/nbsababab/oozie/apps/wf-sqoop/sqoop-import-wf.xml");
        jobProperties.put("oozie.log", "/tmp/log/");
        jobProperties.put("queueName", "ababab");
        jobProperties.put("oozieRoot", "oozie");
        jobProperties.put("oozie.use.system.libpath", "true");
        // Sqoop Import cmd
        jobProperties.put("sqoopImport", "import --connect jdbc:teradata://WDVTERA.xyzyxzxyz.com/database=TESTAB_D,TMODE=TERA,SESSIONS=10 --username "+userId+" --password "+pw+" --table TZ_APP_MAST --target-dir /user/nbsababab/mike/appmast2 -m 1");
        //jobProperties.put("sqoopImport",command);

        // Parameterized
        jobProperties.put("script", "hive-create-external-table.hql");
        jobProperties.put("databaseName", "TEST2");
        jobProperties.put("tableName", "TZ_APP_MAST");
        jobProperties.put("columns", "APP_ID int,APP_NM string,APP_ABBREV_TXT string,APP_TYP_CD int,APP_STAT_CD int,SEC_FLAG_ID int");
        jobProperties.put("delimiter", ",");
        jobProperties.put("location", "/user/nbsababab/mike/appmast2");
    }

    public void createOid() {
        try {
            KERB_V5_OID = new Oid("1.2.840.113554.1.2.2");
            KRB5_PRINCIPAL_NAME_OID = new Oid("1.2.840.113554.1.2.2.1");
        } catch (final GSSException ex) {
            throw new Error(ex);
        }
    }

    public Principal createUserPrincipal(Subject subject) {

        Set<Principal> principalSet = subject.getPrincipals();
        if (principalSet.size() != 1) {
            throw new AssertionError("No or several principals: "+ principalSet);
        }
        Principal userPrincipal = principalSet.iterator().next();
        System.out.println(userPrincipal.toString());
        return userPrincipal;
    }

    private void submitOozieWorkflow(LoginContext lc, Principal userPrincipal) throws LoginException {
        String jobId = null;
        final String userPrincipalName = userPrincipal.getName();

        jobId = Subject.doAsPrivileged(lc.getSubject(),
                new PrivilegedAction<String>() {
                    public String run() {
                        // This is where all secure transaction happen.
                        try {
                            final GSSManager manager = GSSManager.getInstance();
                            GSSName clientName = manager.createName(userPrincipalName, KRB5_PRINCIPAL_NAME_OID);
                            final GSSCredential clientCred = manager.createCredential(clientName, 8 * 3600,
                                            KERB_V5_OID,
                                            GSSCredential.INITIATE_ONLY);

                            final GSSName serverName = manager.createName(
                                    hdfsProperties.getProperty("kerberos.application.principal"),
                                    KRB5_PRINCIPAL_NAME_OID);

                            final GSSContext context = manager.createContext(serverName, KERB_V5_OID, clientCred, GSSContext.DEFAULT_LIFETIME);
                            context.requestMutualAuth(true);
                            context.requestConf(false);
                            context.requestInteg(true);

                            AuthOozieClient wc = new AuthOozieClient(jobProperties.getProperty("oozie_server"));
                            Properties conf = wc.createConfiguration();

                            for (String key : jobProperties.stringPropertyNames()) {
                                String value = jobProperties.getProperty(key);
                                System.out.println(key + " => " + value);

                                conf.setProperty(key,jobProperties.getProperty(key));
                            }
                            System.out.println("Workflow job about to submit");

                            return wc.run(conf);

                        } catch (GSSException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            return null;
                        } catch (OozieClientException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        return null;

                    }
                }// Privillaged action implementation ends here..
                , null);

        System.out.println("jobId:"+jobId);
        lc.logout();
        System.out.println(new Date());
    }
}
```

Stacktrace:

```
11:05:25,749 ERROR [UsersRolesLoginModule] Failed to load users/passwords/role files
java.io.IOException: No properties file: users.properties or defaults: defaultUsers.properties found
    at org.jboss.security.auth.spi.Util.loadProperties(Util.java:198)
    at org.jboss.security.auth.spi.UsersRolesLoginModule.loadUsers(UsersRolesLoginModule.java:186)
    at org.jboss.security.auth.spi.UsersRolesLoginModule.createUsers(UsersRolesLoginModule.java:200)
    at org.jboss.security.auth.spi.UsersRolesLoginModule.initialize(UsersRolesLoginModule.java:127)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invokePriv(Unknown Source)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.login(Unknown Source)
    at test.HelloWorld.login(HelloWorld.java:167)
    at test.HelloWorld.doGet(HelloWorld.java:66)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:190)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:92)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.process(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:126)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:70)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:829)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:598)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
11:05:25,750 ERROR [STDERR] javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: Missing users.properties file.
11:05:25,750 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.security.auth.spi.UsersRolesLoginModule.login(UsersRolesLoginModule.java:148)
11:05:25,751 ERROR [STDERR]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
11:05:25,751 ERROR [STDERR]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
11:05:25,751 ERROR [STDERR]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
11:05:25,751 ERROR [STDERR]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
11:05:25,751 ERROR [STDERR]     at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(Unknown Source)
11:05:25,751 ERROR [STDERR]     at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.access$000(Unknown Source)
11:05:25,751 ERROR [STDERR]     at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(Unknown Source)
11:05:25,751 ERROR [STDERR]     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
11:05:25,751 ERROR [STDERR]     at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invokePriv(Unknown Source)
11:05:25,751 ERROR [STDERR]     at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.login(Unknown Source)
11:05:25,751 ERROR [STDERR]     at test.HelloWorld.login(HelloWorld.java:167)
11:05:25,751 ERROR [STDERR]     at test.HelloWorld.doGet(HelloWorld.java:66)
11:05:25,751 ERROR [STDERR]     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
11:05:25,751 ERROR [STDERR]     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
11:05:25,751 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
11:05:25,752 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
11:05:25,752 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
11:05:25,752 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
11:05:25,752 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
11:05:25,752 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:235)
11:05:25,752 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
11:05:25,752 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:190)
11:05:25,752 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:92)
11:05:25,752 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.process(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:126)
11:05:25,752 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:70)
11:05:25,752 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
11:05:25,752 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
11:05:25,752 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158)
11:05:25,752 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
11:05:25,752 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
11:05:25,753 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:829)
11:05:25,753 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:598)
11:05:25,753 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
11:05:25,753 ERROR [STDERR]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```